# IDbCommand.ExecuteReader reader used with ObjectContext.Translate ignoring mapping/configurations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Using this construct

```
IDbCommand cmd = DbContext.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sproc name";
// param work here
DbContext.Database.Connection.Open();
using (DbDataReader reader = (DbDataReader)cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    result = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.DbContext).ObjectContext.Translate<T>(reader, dbSetName, MergeOption.AppendOnly).ToList();
    // populate
}
```

I get `System.Data.entityCommandExecutionException`:

> {"The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MyModel'. A
>   member of the type, 'ModelMemberName', does not have a corresponding
>   column in the data reader with the same name."}

Now, I do have a mapping for MyModel and cotext's OnModelCreating fires and adds my mapping to DbModelBuilder.Configurations

[ObjectContext.Translate documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) indirectly says that mappings are ignored:

```
The supplied DbDataReader must contain data that maps to the requested entity type
```

But do I have any other avenue to A) execute a sproc and B) honor my mappings?

**EDIT:**
There is an open issue with the EF team, that didn't make it even in 6.1:
[DbContext: Make SqlQuery (etc.) honor [Column]](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/233)